# Xubuntu freezes when a panel item (menu, calendar, program etc.) clicked

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, xubuntu, xfce-panel, amd-ryzen

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 on an ASUS TUF Gaming FX505DD laptop which has Ryzen 5 3550H CPU and NVIDIA GTX1050 GPU. Even when I freshly install the OS and install Nvidia propriety drivers, some time after booting if I click a panel item first it opens after 10 seconds or so and after 3 or 4 clicks the computer gets hard frozen and I have to turn it off using the power button.

I have tried changing GPU driver versions (I tried 435, 440 and 390), clean installs but I wasn't successful at solving the problem.

My kernel version is : 5.30.0.28

Answer (score 0):

update and upgrade you system 
and update gnome and gnome-shell 
 hope it sloves

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install gnome`

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

`sudo apt-get update && upgrade`